# Is it possible to have default distributed Client per thread?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, distributed, dask-dataframe

I have 2 independent remote clusters and running few parallel tasks in different threads that contain Dask DataFrame manipulations. I don't want explicitly use client in each thread - `client.compute(df)`. I want to use default - `df.compute()`.

Is it possible to set default client for each thread?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the solution you are looking for, but one option is to wrap relevant computations in a context manager:

```py
from distributed import Client, LocalCluster
from dask.datasets import timeseries

cluster1 = LocalCluster(n_workers=1, dashboard_address=':0')
cluster2 = LocalCluster(n_workers=1, dashboard_address=':0')

with Client(cluster1) as client:
    print(timeseries().head())

with Client(cluster2) as client:
    print(timeseries().head())
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but as I understood context manager is just for closing the client at the end of the block. When you create Client(cluster) it is equal to Client(clister, set_as_default=True). It means it will conflict between threads.

Comment: Are both clusters on the same machine or they are independent machines? (I'm not sure it matters in the end, but might be useful info)

Comment: Independent remote clusters. More context: I am using Prefect and running 2 parallel tasks that send some Dask DataFrame code to clusters. I want to be sure that each task send code to needed cluster using default Client approach.

Comment: I have already asked in community, but this question is more related to distributed client.